# How can I export my website to PDF and XML with PHP/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, pdf

I'm developing a webform for my company, in which the users will input details about their activities. The company needs that the whole form can be exported to XML and PDF, because we use a DMS engine for many of our operations.
I have two buttons, Save (PDF) and Save (XML).

**Update**

I imported DOMPDF to generate the PDF, 
`index.php` is the site the users will use, and `in.php`, will receive all the changes made on `index.php`, however, I'm screwing up and I don't know where.

**index.php**
    `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario de Visita</title>
        <script src="js/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group" id="section-to-print">
            <div class="container">

                <form class="well form-horizontal"  method="post" id="in.php">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><img src="img/1.png" width="auto" height="65" alt="Imagen Electrónica" /></legend>
             <!-- Información Formulario -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información del Formulario</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombre y dirección del Cliente</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-7">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                                    <select name="empresa" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                      <option value=" ">Seleccione el cliente de esta lista</option>

                                      <?php
                                       $consulta=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
                                       while($dato=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){

                                      ?>
                                        <option><?php echo $dato["Nombre"].', '.$dato["direccion"]; ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                      }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <!-- Información Entrada -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información - Entrada</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fecha</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <input name="fechaent" class="form-control" type="date">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Hora</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <input class="hentrada" id="event_start_time" name="event[start_time]" type="time" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Técnico</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                    <input name="tecnico" placeholder="Correo del Técnico" class="form-control" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <!-- Información Salida -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información - Salida</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <input class="hsalida" id="event_start_time" name="event[end_time]" type="time" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Razón de la Visita</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="razonvisita" placeholder="Describa el objetivo del cliente con su visita acá"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Trabajo Realizado</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="trabajorealizado" placeholder="Describa el trabajo que realizó durante la visita."></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Comentarios</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="comentarios" placeholder=""></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                    <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma1"></script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                    <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma2"></script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="print" action="print_pdf.php" name="crear"> Enviar (PDF) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name='submit' value='submit'> Enviar (XML) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
        <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>`
```

**in.php:**

```
<?php 
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['empresa']= $_POST["empresa"];
    $_SESSION['fechaent']= $_POST["fechaent"];
    $_SESSION['horaent']= $_POST["event[start_time]"];
    $_SESSION['tecnico']= $_POST["tecnico"];
    $_SESSION['horasal']= $_POST["event[end_time]"];
    $_SESSION['rvisita']= $_POST["razonvisita"];
    $_SESSION['comentarios']= $_POST["comentarios"];
    $_SESSION['trabajor']= $_POST["trabajorealizado"];
$codigoHTML='
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario de Visita</title>
        <script src="js/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="css/bootstrapValidator.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group" id="section-to-print">
            <div class="container">

                <form class="well form-horizontal"  method="post" id="contact_form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><img src="img/1.png" width="auto" height="65" alt="Imagen Electrónica" /></legend>
             <!-- Información Formulario -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información del Formulario</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombre y dirección del Cliente</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-7">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="empresa" id="event_start_time" value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['empresa'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
          <!-- Información Entrada -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información - Entrada</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fecha</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                  <input class="form-control" name="fechaent" id="event_start_time" value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['fechaent'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Hora</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                  <input class="form-control" name="hentrada" id="event_start_time" value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['hentrada'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Técnico</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                  <input class="form-control" name="tecnico" id="event_start_time" value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['tecnico'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
      <!-- Información Salida -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información - Salida</label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                  <input class="form-control" name="hsalida" id="event_start_time" value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['hsalida'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Razón de la Visita</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" name="razonvisita" placeholder="Describa el objetivo del cliente con su visita acá" value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['rvisita'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/> 
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Trabajo Realizado</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" name="trabajorealizado" placeholder="Describa el trabajo que realizó durante la visita." value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['trabajor'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Comentarios</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" name="comentarios" placeholder="" value="';
                                    $codigoHTML.=''.$dato['comentarios'].'';

                                    $codigoHTML.='
                                    "/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 1</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                  <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma1"></script>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 2</label>
                          <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                  <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma2"></script>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
                  </fieldset>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>';
$codigoHTML=utf8_decode($codigoHTML);
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($empresa.$fechaent.".pdf");
?>
```

`$dompdf->stream($empresa.$fechaent.".pdf";` is to dinamically generate the name of the document, it needs to be unique in order to be saved into our servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window.print method to print and also u can save to file from the preview.

```
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.print();
    });
```

through the click function

```
 <button type="button" id="print" class="btn btn-default" >Print Report</button>
```

also include css style for printing it

```
 @media print {
        body * {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
            visibility: visible;
            color: white;
        }

        #section-to-print {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    }
```

'section-to-print" will be the printing div id

```
<div id="section-to-print">
  <p>your contents here</p>
</div>
```

check this working fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/pb7ve1u3/5/

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely give it a try, though I need to save the PDFs into the server, not the local machine.